# Get inline URL when changing

Tags: jquery, url, inline, fetch

How is it possible - in jQuery- to fetch the URL when clicking inline links like following?

```
http://domain.com/#!/?model=ford
http://domain.com/#!/?color=blue
```

Following code grabs when you reload the whole browser, but not when you click the "inline links"

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

A site using the technique Im looking for is the following: http://www.modezine.com/se/#!/?category=women 
Try pressing the different colors and look at the URL and the content being reloaded without browser reload.

Comment: (offtopic) ahem... if you wait a bit longer sorry, we were looking the pics!

Comment: Actually, that site reloads in my browser when clicking the colors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in firebug while clicking the different colors, the call is made via AJAX.
Grabs the desired URI content and pushes it into place (this technique will not refresh the page, but the URL is "prettyfied").

So my answer is : go for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Don't miss this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax

Comment: Thanks for the answer it put me in the direction of finding this thread on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery with this neat solution: $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  .. work ..
});

Comment: Thanks was about to write it. Nice research.